# Compute trajectory using unit of measure

Tags: .net, f#, units-of-measurement

I am learning F# and I am trying to use for the first time the concept of Unit of Measure. I have the following questions:

- The last let (variable y in the getPosition function gives me the following error: "The unit of measure ''u ^ 2 m/second' does not match the unit of measure 'm'". Is there something wrong in the formula or it is my usage os unit of measure?
- I am using the Unit of Measures defined in Microsoft.FSharp.Data.UnitSystems.SI. Is there a way to not specify the use a shorter version of the name? (e.g. UnitNames.second vs second).
- I have to use the function cos and sin. These two functions expect a float, not a float. I use LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure to convert the float into a unit of measure. Is this the only way to do that? It makes the code very verbose.

Thanks!

```
open System
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.UnitSystems.SI

module GeneralBallisticTrajectory = 
    [<Measure>] type radian

    let gravitationalAcceleration : float<UnitNames.metre/UnitNames.second^2> = 9.80665<UnitNames.metre/UnitNames.second^2>

    let getPosition (angle: float<radian>) (velocity: float<UnitNames.metre/UnitNames.second>)  (t: float<UnitNames.second>) =
        let x = velocity * t * (cos (float angle) |> LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure<UnitNames.metre/UnitNames.second>)
        let abc = (0.5 * gravitationalAcceleration) * t * t // returns float<UnitNames.metre>

        // The unit of measure 'UnitNames.metre' does not match the unit of measure 'UnitNames.metre ^ 2/UnitNames.second'
        let y = (velocity * t * (sin (float angle) |> LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure<UnitNames.metre/UnitNames.second>)) - abc

        (x, y)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the shorter names by adding an

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.UnitSystems.SI.UnitNames
```

to your file.

As for the error, it's not clear why you are converting the result of the `sin` call to a measure type, since `velocity * t` has the same measure type (meter) as `abc`. The following appears to be what you want:

```
open System
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.UnitSystems.SI
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.UnitSystems.SI.UnitNames

module GeneralBallisticTrajectory = 
    [<Measure>] type radian

    let gravitationalAcceleration : float<metre/second^2> = 9.80665<metre/second^2>

    let getPosition (angle: float<radian>) (velocity: float<metre/second>)  (t: float<second>) =
        let x = velocity * t * (cos (float angle) |> LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure<metre/second>)
        let abc = (0.5 * gravitationalAcceleration) * t * t // returns float<UnitNames.metre>

        let y = (velocity * t * (sin (float angle))) - abc
        (x, y)
```